# Flutter : Adding TextField and Getting Value From it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, textfield

I am trying to add two TextField and there will be two parts inside them. One of them will be Student No and the second will be School No.

When I write 1234 in a text field used for student no and 4321 in a text field for school no, I have to get them and put somewhere inside code as seen here;

Here is the code block I am using here;

```
        class DocUploadScreen extends StatefulWidget {
        createState() => _DocUploadScreenState();
            }

         class _DocUploadScreenState extends State<DocUploadScreen> {

         File _imageFile;

         Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
         File selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

         setState(() {
         _imageFile = selected;
          });
            }

         void _clear() {
         setState(() => _imageFile = null);
              }

         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("FÖY YÜKLEME EKRANI"),
           ),
           bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
           child: Row(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
           children: <Widget>[
             IconButton(
             icon: Icon(
             Icons.photo_camera,
             size: 30,
              ),
                onPressed: () => _pickImage(ImageSource.camera),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
                 IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(
                  Icons.photo_library,
                  size: 30,
                 ),
                    onPressed: () => _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery),
                    color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                         ],
                            ),
                                ),
                        body: ListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          if (_imageFile != null) ...[
                            Container(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.all(32), child: Image.file(_imageFile)),
                              Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                               children: <Widget>[
                               FlatButton(
                               color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                                 onPressed: _clear,
                                   ),
                                     ],
                                        ),
                                           Padding(
                                           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                                           child: Uploader(
                                           file: _imageFile,
                                            ),
                                                )
                                                   ]
                                                       ],
                                                            ),
                                                                );
                                                                   }
                                                                      }

            class Uploader extends StatefulWidget {
            final File file;

             Uploader({Key key, this.file}) : super(key: key);

             createState() => _UploaderState();
                }

               class _UploaderState extends State<Uploader> {
               final FirebaseStorage _storage =
                FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://emo-is0.appspot.com');

                 StorageUploadTask _uploadTask;

                  _startUpload() async {
```

I will put values getting from text fields(schoolno and studentno):

```
                   String filePath = 'schoolno/studentno/documents/${DateTime.now()}.png';



                   StorageUploadTask _uploadTask = 
                              _storage.ref().child(filePath).putFile(widget.file);

                      StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await _uploadTask.onComplete;
                     Navigator.push(
                       context,
                           MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                     (InvoiceUploadScreen())));
                                 }
```

I have 2 questions here;

1. Where I need to put TextFields so I can get values and put on the place seen below,
2. How can I get values from TextFields and put it on? And also how can I use a validator inside the text field since both school and student no have to be given in order to be used for uploading to storage?

Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve a value from textfield the best way is using TextEditingController you will pass the controller to the TextField and you can access the text by using the controller with the text value.

```
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController():

TextField(
 controller: controller,
)
```

To access the text you use controller.text you can even update the value of the text if wanted.

I'm not sure what exactly you mean with the validators.

Comment: Inside my code block, where should I put these codes to be achieved for textfield. With validator textfield must be filled with values. If empty textfield occurs, ıt should give error saying that textfields can not be empty

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st question is very confusing. TextField is a widget, so it'll be placed inside Widget build() {}.

If you don't understand what a widget is, I suggest reading the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro). If what you want is "where to put on the UI", then it's up to you.

For your 2nd question, as @ayad's answer, use a TextEditingController that hold the value of the Textfield. For validation of TextField, there's also a [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation) about it.